# Onblur is automatically called on OnFocus event in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working in react. I wanted to show text box on click of a button and trying to show the suggestions onFocusing the Text box. So i tried with `OnFocus()` event and i want to hide the suggestion when we click out of the textbox so i used `onBlur()` event. its working fine when i manually focusing the text box.

When i tried to put the focus automatically when the button is clicked then the onBlur() is also triggered and hiding the suggestions. I don't know why. Help me to overcome this issue.

Code :

```
<input type="text" tabIndex="1"   onFocus={//focus handler//} placeholder="Enter Search value" ref="search_txt"  onBlur={this.onBlurEvent} />

componentDidMount(){
       this.refs.search_txt.focus();
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a full code, that would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below link

https://coderwall.com/p/0iz_zq/how-to-put-focus-at-the-end-of-an-input-with-react-js

```
moveCaretAtEnd(e) {
  var temp_value = e.target.value
  e.target.value = ''
  e.target.value = temp_value
}


render() {
  <textarea 
    value={value}
    autoFocus
    onFocus={this.moveCaretAtEnd}
  ></textarea>
}
```